# Symfony2 Collection of forms automatically persisted

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I'm trying to embed a collection of forms. I have a task form which contains a collection of tag forms:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('tags', 'collection', array('type' => new TagType()));
}
```

The task entity contains the one-to-many relation to the tag (without cascade persist):

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Tag", mappedBy="task", cascade={"remove"})
 */
protected $tags;
```

The tag entity contains the many-to-one relation to the task:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Task", inversedBy="tags")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="task_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $task;
```

I now have a Controller, which can edit all tags of its task. If the form is submitted and valid, I would like to iterate through all tags and decide whether to save the tag or not, but in my case, if `$em->flush()` is called, every Tag is updated and persisted automatically, without even calling `$em->persist()` on the task or on any tags.

```
public function editTaskAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $task = $em->getRepository('AcmeTaskBundle:Task')->find($id);
    $form = $this->createForm(new TaskType(), $task);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid())
    {
        foreach ($task->getTags() as $tag)
        {
            // TODO decide whether to save the tag or not
        }

        $em->flush();
    }

    return array('form' => $form->createView());
}
```

I don't really understand what I'm missing here. Where exactly is the data persisted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [skowron-line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23708941/1093554) I ended up using a lifecycle callback within my tag entity class:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs;

/**
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Tag
{
    /**
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $event)
    {
        if ($event->getEntity() instanceof Tag)
        {
            if ($event->hasChangedField('name') && $conditionToAvoidUpdatingEntity)
            {
                $event->setNewValue('name', $event->getOldValue('name'));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you retrieve `$task` with the EntityManager (`$task = $em->getRepository('AcmeTaskBundle:Task')->find($id);`), this Entity is automatically managed by the EntityManager, so `$em->persist($task);` is implicit.

This isn't the case for example on your `createTaskAction()` where you get your Task by creating it (`$task = new Task();`)

In your case, the best is probably to remove the Tags you don't need in your `foreach ($task->getTags() as $tag)` by doing something like `$task->removeTag($tag);` for any unwanted tag.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right place to do this. You should use `prePersist` in which you have access to all data send to DB. There You can decide whether or not insert new row.
Here is the [example](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-callbacks) how lifecycle works.